# A certain O(lgN) process requires 10 seconds to process 1024 items

Tags: performance, time-complexity

A certain O(lgN) process requires 10 seconds to process 1024 items. 
How long would it take for it to process 2048 items? 
How long would it take for it to process 2048 items? 
Answer similar questions of O(N lgN) O(N) O(N*N). 
My teacher taught this but it was really confusing... can anyone teach me how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: There is insufficient information to answer the question.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm not sure I get your comment (assuming it's a simple theoretical question, not a practical one)

Comment: @dystroy: O(N) only describes the asymptotic behavior.  It provides *zero* information on how close a problem with 1024 items lies to the asymptotic limit.  apomeme's answer gives the idea, but there actually may be far more than two terms (unknown coefficients).  For example, `O(lg N)` may have a term of `lg lg N` in addition to the `lg N` and constant terms apomene mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

O(lgN) means that the evaluation function is:

```
F(N)=algN+b
```

since `F(1024)=10` we get:

```
alg(2^10)+b=10 => 10a+b=10=> (one possible solution) a=1 and b=0
```

so we have:

```
F(N)=lgN
```

so:

```
 F(2048)=lg(2^11)= 11 sec
```

The same logic goes for O(NlgN),...

Comment: Thanks! I see what you did there, I have the chart for future problems.

Answer (score 2):

```
T(1024) = 10s = K*log(1024)
T(2048) = K*log(2048)
```

so

```
T(2048) = 10*log(2048)/log(1024)
T(2048) = 11s
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `11s`?

Comment: @Bergi Yes... Multiplying 10 by 1.1 is obviously too complex for my small head ^^